# Can you have patch.multiple where new_callable is set for each patch?

Tags: mocking, pytest, patch, fixtures

I have this fixture to get all tests in this file to use a pytest temporary directory for the files and directories used by the code:

```
import src.recurrent_admin.restic_backup_task as restic_task 
...

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_path_strs(tmpdir):        
    tmpdir_path = pathlib.Path(str(tmpdir))
    testing_repo_dir_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('repo_dir')
    mock_repo_dir_path_str = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=(str(testing_repo_dir_path)))
    testing_pwd_file_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('pwd_file.txt')
    mock_pwd_file_path_str = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=(str(testing_pwd_file_path)))
    testing_src_dir_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('src_dir')
    mock_src_dir_path_str = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=(str(testing_src_dir_path)))
    with mock.patch.object(restic_task, 'REPO_DIR_PATH_STR', new_callable=mock_repo_dir_path_str):
        with mock.patch.object(restic_task, 'PWD_FILE_PATH_STR', new_callable=mock_pwd_file_path_str):
            with mock.patch.object(restic_task, 'SRC_DIR_PATH_STR', new_callable=mock_src_dir_path_str):
                yield
```

This does the job... but I was wondering whether it's possible to use `mock.patch.multiple`, but somehow set `new_callable` for each individual item?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no need for `PropertyMock` here. This works for this simple case:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_path_strs(tmpdir):        
    tmpdir_path = pathlib.Path(str(tmpdir))
    testing_repo_dir_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('restic', 'repo_dir')
    testing_pwd_file_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('restic', 'pwd_file.txt')
    testing_src_dir_path = tmpdir_path.joinpath('restic', 'src_dir')
    with mock.patch.multiple(restic_task, REPO_DIR_PATH_STR=str(testing_repo_dir_path), PWD_FILE_PATH_STR=str(testing_pwd_file_path), 
        SRC_DIR_PATH_STR=str(testing_src_dir_path) ):
        yield
```